# How to use Multi Tracker with OpenCV 4.6?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-tracking

I am trying to track multiple objects and to do so I am using a Multi Tracker.
This is the part of my code that should initialize the tracker:

```
multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()

for box in boxes:
  multiTracker.add(cv2.TrackerKCF_create(), frame, box)
```

When I run the code the following error appears:

```
    multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'MultiTracker_create'
```

I already try to use `cv2.MultiTracker` instead of `cv2.MultiTracker_create`but nothing works. I already tried `cv2.legacy.MultiTracker`but, again, it didn't work.
Is there any way to use this MultiTracker with OpenCV 4.6? If not what's the new alternative? I did some research but I didn't find relevant information.

UPDATE:
After adding `legacy` to `cv2.TrackerKCF_create()` the error disappeared.

```
multiTracker = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()

for box in boxes:
  multiTracker.add(cv2.legacy.TrackerKCF_create(), frame, box)
```

Comment: here's a C++ example. does that help? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d07/tutorial_multitracker.html

Comment: From what I understood they use `legacy::MultiTracker trackers;` to create the trackers. In python, I am using the same module `cv2.MultiTracker_create()`. I already tested `cv2.MultiTracker()`,  `cv2.legacy.MultiTracker`, and `cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create`  but neither of these optionss are supported.

Comment: make sure you have the contrib variant installed, not the base variant of the package (and none concurrently, they conflict). -- the `..._create()` stuff is right. most opencv classes use this idiom of a factory method. -- I can call `trackers = cv.legacy.MultiTracker_create()` -- your question ends ("update:...") as if everything is resolved now. do you have any questions/issues left? remember, Stack Overflow encourages answering your own questions, in the SO question-answer format. someone else might find your question and would be happy to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some changes, I founs a solution.
I am using the [TrackerKCF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dff/classcv_1_1TrackerKCF.html), with OpenCV 4.6, and this is my solution:

```
multiTracker = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()

for box in boxes:
  multiTracker.add(cv2.legacy.TrackerKCF_create(), frame, box)
```